# What's the theme here? (#4)

Tags: visual, knowledge

Here's the fourth installment.

Pictures with a Common Theme:

1. [image] 2. [image]

3. [image] 4. [image]

5. [image] 6. [image]

7. [image] 8.[image]

9. [image] 10. [image]

---

Hint:

> Think **GAME**

---

Comment: My original thought was Disneyland rides.  The Matterhorn Bobsleds (3), Space Mountain (4), and Pirates of the Caribbean (6) fit so well, but I couldn't figure out the rest.  But given the hint, this was clearly the wrong direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the theme to be:

> Super Mario 64

As suggested by previous answers:

> Each image represents a world in the game.

1.

> **Shifting Sand Land** -- the image may represent the process of sand dune formation

2.

> **Lethal Lava Land**, a world located upon a lava ocean/lake not unlike what is pictured here

3.

> **Cool, Cool Mountain**, a snow/ice level with a central peak

4.

> **Tall, Tall Mountain**, a level centered entirely on a (you guessed it) very large, tall mountain

5.

> Could be **Dry Dry Docks** based on the water and what appears to be a dock in the background. (EDIT: Whoops, mixed up my words! s/Dry/**Dire**)

6.

> **Jolly Roger Bay**, due to the presence of a pirate ship upon water, which are both prominent in this level.

7.

> Could be **Wet Dry World**, as the vacuum pictured would work in either case.

8.

> **Tick-Tock Clock** (Tick, tock, it's a clock!)

9.

> Looks like a shimmering figure in an entryway...so perhaps **Hazy Maze Cave**?

10.

> Tricky one, but I'm thinking **Bob-omb Battlefield**...one of the castle's stars is guarded by a big Chain Chomp, which barks like a dog.

---

Update to 10.:

> Credit to @Pugmonkey in a comment to Joe-You-Know's answer for identifying the dog as "Boo", this one is probably **Big Boo's Haunt**, although it features a ghost, not a puppy. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Taking a super wild guess here, but is it:

> Banjo Kazzoie

Here is my (quite flawed, I think) logic:

> According to the Wiki, these are the worlds in the game:

_

> Spiral Mountain | Hub World | Gruntilda's Lair | Mumbo's Mountain  Treasure Trove Cove | Clanker's Cavern |

_

> Bubblegloop Swamp | Freezeezy Peak | Gobi's Valley | Mad Monster

_

> Mansion |  Rusty Bucket Bay |  **Click  Clock Wood**

_

> Alot of these worlds resemble the images in the OP post. There's the obvious mountains/hills etc, but there is also the Large Clock which matches with Click Clock Wood.

_

> I also looked into a couple of spin offs of the game, trying to see if I can match something else up.

Either way,

> It's probably a video game, and probably refers to the worlds in the game.

_

> (ALSO, I Reverse-Image-Searched the first image and Google Said it was about "deposition features of wind")

Comment: Huh! I got "depositional *features* of wind." I wonder what the wind is "depositionaling?" :)

Comment: BTW, your "Either way" thoughts are both very much correct, it's just not the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is:

> Castle Crashers (or The Benemoth itself)

@Aryaman discovered:

> The answer is a game and the images are worlds in a game.

Explanation:

> Most of this images are levels in the game castle crashers. Some of these I didn't find but I found the levels

1.

> Desert level

2.

> Lava level

3.

> Snow world

4.

> ?

5.

> Dock Level

6.

> Pirate ship level

7.

> Probably a stretch but the game Battleblock theater (The same creators of Castle Crashers has a [Vacuum](http://battleblocktheater.wikia.com/wiki/Vacuum)

8.

> Battleblock theater also has time trial maps

9.

> Pipistrello's Cave

10.

> [Pazzo](http://castlecrashers.wikia.com/wiki/Pazzo) looks like a shiba inu

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely satisfied with this answer, but it fits some of the images:

The theme is:

> Kingdom Hearts

1.

> Agrabah.  The image is the mechanism of sand dune formation / migration.

2. ???

3.

> The North Mountain from Frozen (actually the Matterhorn)

4.

> Olympus Coliseum - the largest mountain is Olympus Mons on Mars

5. ???

6.

> The Jolly Roger

7. ???

8.

> The Clocktower (Big Ben) in Neverland World

9.

> The Cave of Wonders

10.

> Monsters Inc World (the dog pictured is Boo, the self-described "cutest dog in the world").  This could also be the Pride Lands since the dog looks vaguely like a lion

Comment: I'd pay big bucks to see a dog "self-describe." :)

Comment: It has it's own Facebook page, so I wouldn't put anything past it.  Seriously, people go to embarrassing lengths to humanize their pets.

Comment: And you're right; "self-described" is probably going a little too far.   :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> The Super Mario Games/World

1.

> Clearly a sand level, obviously World 2 in most games.

2.

> Clearly a lava level, most likely found in World 8 in most games.

3.

> The ice/snow levels found in World 5.

4.

> Possibly Super Mario Galaxies, as it features more worlds (you show a mountain of Mars).

5.

> Dire Dire Docks in Super Mario 64 or maybe Super Mario Sunshine and Isle Delfino

6.

> Pirate Land featured in Mario Party 2

7.

> Luigi's Mansion, with his Poltergust

8.

> Maybe referencing Mario & Luigi: Partners in Time

9.

> Any of the tunnel or cave levels.

10.

> @Pugmonkey, boo the cutest dog in the world. So this is either King Boo, or many of the boos in the Super Mario World.

Comment: For 10, I believe the dog pictured is named rot13("obb gur phgrfg qbt va gur jbeyq").  That would fit your answer well.